# Parse Push Notification not work on android

Tags: android, push-notification, parse-platform

I am using parse push notification for my android app.
I follow tutorial and i downlaod jar file and than import it into my project and i have added this code into my manifest

```
<service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
<receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
</intent-filter>
```

Also i have added application.class into  my my package and code is

```
public class Application extends android.app.Application {

    public Application() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // Initialize the Parse SDK.
        Parse.initialize(this, "zzxxxxxxxxxxxxxxVv", "wyxxxxxxxCElxxxxxxx"); 

        // Specify a Activity to handle all pushes by default.
        PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, MainActivity.class);

        // Save the current installation.
        ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
    }
}
```

In my main activity i do this

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(getIntent());

    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    Log.e("MainActivity", "oncreate");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

Some says that it problem with name attribut in application in manifest so i aaded this line wiht my pacakge name

```
 <application
    android:name="com.test.pushnotificationTest.Application"
```

In parse dashboard when i install app into new device than i get new entry into dashboard..but when i try to send push notification i dont get it.
Do i need to add brodcast receiver?? but it was working before with same code without broadcast
help me guys

Comment: did you check your parse authentics? the codes for your app.

Comment: @user2558344 you mean to say application id and client id right?...yes i check that

Comment: Can you add some detail describing how you are sending these notifications and to which installations they are targeted?

Comment: @HectorRamos i send notification by using parse https://parse.com and it sends notification and by using application id and KEY Parse.initialize() it identify which application need to display notification...this is how parse tutorial says am i right?

Comment: have you enabled the push notifiaction settings @ parse.com?

Comment: @user2558344 yes i did that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

parse api sometimes lags for push message delivery for android...
i got push notification when i signed my apk.. try it again with signed apk.

Comment: just make sure that port 8253 is open if you are behind a firewall

Comment: @muayyadalsadi how do I unblock port 8253?

Answer (score 3):

The parse notifier uses port number 8253.
If it is blocked in your network the notification will not be received!!!
So try some other internet connection  ...this is how i solved this problem!

Comment: is it blocked by default or you had an app using that port

Answer (score 1):

there should be 2 receiver tags. other one should be something like this

```
<receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <!--
                  IMPORTANT: If you change the package name of this sample app,
                  change "com.parse.tutorials.pushnotifications" in the lines
                  below to match the new package name.
                -->
                <category android:name="com.example.ifis" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

add this into your delegate or activity on onCreate

```
ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("[channel name]", new SaveCallback() {
          @Override
          public void done(ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
              Log.d("com.parse.push", "successfully subscribed to the broadcast channel.");
            } else {
              Log.e("com.parse.push", "failed to subscribe for push", e);
            }
          }
        });
```

Comment: is this really necessary to add?